# How to determine why my Python code takes infinite time to run

Tags: python, oop, file-io

I learned a little bit of OOP and file I/O. I tried to apply them to real-life by making my own code. Unfortunately, however, it doesn't run. Python never says there is an error. It is just executing command all day and saying please wait for the result.

Here is my code:

```
class CoursesTaken():

    def __init__(self):
        self._courses = []

    def read_file(self, file):
        line = file.readline().strip()
        while line != 0:
            course = tuple(line.split())
            self._courses.append(course)

    def add_course(self, season, code, gpa):
        self._course = (season, code, gpa)
        self._courses.append(self._course)

    def total_courses(self):
        return self._courses

    def name_of_total_courses(self):
        result = []
        for i in self._courses:
            name = i[1]
            result.append(name)
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = open('courses.txt')
    courses = CoursesTaken()
    courses.read_file(file)
    print(courses.name_of_total_courses)
    file.close()
```

txt file is in this format:

2018S CSC111 A

2018S MAT101 B+

I have no idea how to improve my code.

Comment: Why would `line` ever be equal to `0`?

Comment: You are always splitting the same line.

Comment: from doc: if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached. Not `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of writing an infinite loop.

The three necessary components for creating while loop are

1. Making a comparision
2. Code Body
3. Updating the comparison variable

You have the first two parts. However, the line:

```
line = file.readline().strip()
```

is outside of your while loop. Line will never be anything but the first line you assigned it to. The easiest way to solve this is add another

```
line = file.readline().strip()
while line != 0:
    course = tuple(line.split())
    self._courses.append(course)
    line = file.readline().strip()
```

As @nosklo said: the correct way to do the while loop is not to compare to zero. I usually prefer

```
while line:
    # code
```

Comment: also, readline() returns strings so the condition itself will never be False.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @nosklo Thank you, I had forgotten that you can just do while line:

Answer (score 3):

your problem is in this snippet:

```
line = file.readline().strip()
while line != 0:
```

`line` will never be `== 0` since it is a string and `0` is a integer. They will never compare equal in python, so your loop repeats forever. Also, you do nothing inside the loop to change the value of the `line` variable. It will forever hold the first value assigned before the loop starts, the condition will never change.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't fix my problem after changing it to while line != '':

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* iterate over the contents of a file using a `while` loop and explicit calls to `readline`, there is no reason to do so.

```
def read_file(self, file):
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        course = tuple(line.split())
        self._courses.append(course)
```

which could be condensed even further:

```
def read_file(self, file):
    self._courses.extend(tuple(line.strip().split()) for line in file)
```

---

If you choose to use a `while` loop, you are responsible for calling `readline` once per iteration, to get a newline, until it returns an empty string.

```
def read_file(self, file):
    line = file.readline().strip()
    while line != "":
        self._courses.append(tuple(line.split()))
        line = file.readline().strip()
```